# display series of images on button click

Tags: javascript

is it possible to display 3 images one after another at each button click using a array in JavaScript?
I have an array called

```
var images = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"]
```

The way I need the website to load is for the first picture to already be there. Then when I click on the button I want the next picture to be displayed however replacing the image that was there before. I want this to repeat throughout the entire, so when I click on the button, and if the image being displayed was image3, then image1 should be displayed.

I want to share the code I have so far however I don't know where to start. the only code i have is the layout and a variable.

```
var images = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.Use 'document.querySelector' do select your button.On clicking button appen images using `forEach` in body.

```js
   var button = document.querySelector('#show');//selects your button
    button.addEventListener('click',function(){ // handle click event
    var images = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];//array of valid images
    images.forEach(function(image){
    img = document.createElement('img');//creates a img element
    img.src = image;//sets src of img tag
    document.body.appendChild(img)//appends into body
    });
    });
```

```html
    <button id="show">
    Show images
    </button>
```

Comment: Think the OP wanted to switch the image based on button click, not show all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JS** solution.

```js
var images = ["http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/250x150", "http://placehold.it/150x150"];

var elem = document.getElementById('img');
var i = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  elem.setAttribute("src", images[i]);
}

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  (i < images.length-1) ? i++ : i = 0;
  this.setAttribute("src", images[i]);
});
```

```html
<img src='' id='img'>
```

**jQuery** solution.

```js
var images = ["http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/250x150", "http://placehold.it/150x150"];
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#img').attr('src', images[i]);
});

$('#img').click(function() {
  (i < images.length-1) ? i++ : i = 0;
  $('#img').attr('src', images[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='' id='img'>
```